# having issue in multiplayer game using Photon Pun2(Info gamer)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I'm working on a multiplayer game where i'm having an issue that is i have a `spanwer(PlayerAvatar)` that instantiates my character that i choose out of an array but the problem is that that character that i choose instantiate as child of `PlayerAvatar(spawner`) and my movement script is attached to the character that i choose that is child of `PlayerAvatar(spawner)`.

When i move my character that i choose and that is child the parent `PlayerAvatar(Spawner)` doesn't move because my movement script is attached to the child and all the network info like Network ID is attached to the PlayerAvatar so if `PayerAvatar(Spawner and parent)`doesn't move my movement of the character(child) doesn't synchronize to the other player who is connected with me through internet and same problem with other player his movement doesn't synchronize on my side.

so if anyone can help me out through this problem!!

[image]

```
private PhotonView PV;
public GameObject myAvatar;

void Start()
{
    PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    int spawnPicker = Random.Range(0, GameSetup.GS.spawnPoints.Length);
    if (PV.IsMine)
    {
        myAvatar = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(
            Path.Combine("Prefabs", "PlayerAvatar"),
            GameSetup.GS.spawnPoints[spawnPicker].position, 
            GameSetup.GS.spawnPoints[spawnPicker].rotation, 
            0
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add all classes related to this issue? e.g. PlayerAvatar (Spawner and parent)
They should be 2 different classes

Comment: Please also rephrase the title of your question .. it is very generic

Comment: Is your PhotonView and PhotonTransformView attached to the moving object? And are you ensuring that your local key input etc. code only steers those objects where `!photonView.IsMine` (or `!photonView.Owner.IsLocal`)? (By the way, if you define your class to be MonoBehaviourPun instead of MonoBehaviour, then the photonView will already exist for you at all times, and doesn't need to be referenced in Start.)

Comment: ok guys thanks to all of you guys i sorted that issue out!!

Comment: you should tell us how you sorted it out and what was the issue

Comment: yeah sure my issue is explain above and how i sorted out is i updated my instantiating script little but and that is that i gave them id that if i select character with id 1 that it instantiate that character and with id 2 instantiate other character

 if (PlayerInfo.PI.mySelectedCharacter == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("E38");
                myAvatar = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("Prefabs", "E38"),
                    GameSetup.GS.spawnPoints[spawnPicker].position, GameSetup.GS.spawnPoints[spawnPicker].rotation, 0);
            }

Comment: i'm trying to update the post but idk i'm getting errors updating my post with u[dated script and picture so i pasted some of my script idk if you guys can understand this or not